# Need help implementing simple role management

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a very basic need in regards to membership and role management.  I am having success with the membership and being able to use the [Authorize] filter, but the IsInRole() and all that goes along with it is failing.  I am hoping someone can point out where I am going wrong.

1) Login action is called on the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LoginVM model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (_employeeService.Login(model))
            {
                _employeeService.CreateTicket(model);

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

2) The CreateTicket(LovinVM model) looks like this:

```
public HttpCookie CreateTicket(LoginVM input)
    {
        string rolesList;
        using (var tx = _session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            Employee employee = _employeeRepository.GetByUsername(input.Username);

            if (employee.Roles.Count >= 0)
            {
                string[] roles = new string[employee.Roles.Count];
                for (int i = 0; i < employee.Roles.Count; i++)
                {
                    roles[i] = employee.Roles.ElementAt(i).Name;
                }

                rolesList = string.Join(",", roles);
            }
            else
            {
                rolesList = string.Empty;
            }

            tx.Commit();
        }

        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, input.Username, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), false, rolesList);

        return new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket));
    }
```

If I check to see if the user is in a role after the ticket is created, but before the auth cookie is set I get a true value:

```
_employeeService.CreateTicket(model);

bool test = User.IsInRole("Role1");

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, model.RememberMe);
```

If I add a check to the site.master to show/hide a menu item based on role there are no roles listed for the user anymore.  I have tried both Page.User.IsInRole("Role1") and HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Role1") neither of which is true.  I also receive a failure on [Authorize(Roles="Role1")] filter.

Comment: Did you re-hydrate the Identity object in the global.asax?

Comment: Can you expand on this a little bit? I'm not clear on what you mean.

Comment: Well this was the answer but I can't mark a comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you are basing your membership off of the old base membership provider or not, but looking at one of my early stage MVC projects... there is a method being called when a user successfully validates ...

```
if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
```

While I am no expert on Membership services, it sounds as if your user is not properly being Logged in, once they "Log In" if you know what I mean.

The line that says FormsService.SignIn() ... you have nothing similar in your LogOn method.

Comment: That is where if (_employeeService.Login(model)) comes in on mine.  I will double check that I did not miss something within that call though.  Thank you.

Comment: Ahh ok - I guess your employeeService.Login method is overriding the FormsService.SignIn() method.

Answer (score 0):

on a separate note - Im curious why you are calling commit on a transaction when it seems as though no transactional work is being done? You get a user, and create a ticket (which goes to a cookie.

Comment: It is not absolutely necessary, but I use it so I don't get the alerts when using nhprof. http://nhprof.com/Learn/Alerts/AvoidImplicitRollback